# Model mapper not mapping values

Tags: spring-boot, modelmapper

I am mapping a collection with a collection.Its getting mapped successfully most of  time but sometime its getting failed and i am getting null values.

```
    ArrayList<RiskRequestDTO> riskList = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterable<Risk> risks = RiskRepository.findAll();

    if (risks != null) {
        java.lang.reflect.Type targetListType = new TypeToken<List<riskRequestDTO>>() {
        }.getType();

        riskList = modelMapper.map(risks, targetListType);
    }
```

**Risk DTO**

i am facing some issue to add complete code so i removed setters and getters.I am confirming that the relevant annotations are present with setters and getters

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "riskId", "localeTranslations", "lastModifiedAt", "lastModifiedBy"
})

public class RiskRequestDTO {

    @JsonProperty("riskId")
    private int riskId;
    @JsonProperty("localeTranslations")
    private Set<LocaleTranslation> localeTranslations;
    @JsonProperty("lastModifiedAt")
    private Date lastModifiedAt;
    @JsonProperty("lastModifiedBy")
    private UserViewDTO lastModifiedBy;
```

**Risk Model**

I am facing some issue to add complete code so i removed setters and getters of these entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "risk")
public class Risk {

    /**
     * risk_id , primary key.
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = “risk_id")
    private int riskId;

    /**
     * last modified date.
     */
    @Column(name = "last_modified_at")
    private Date lastModifiedAt;

    /**
     * details of locale.
     */
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="risk_to_local_translation", joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="risk_id") }, inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="locale_translation_id") })
    private Set<LocaleTranslation> localeTranslations;

    /**
     * details of the user who updated the recommendations.
     */
    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "last_modified_by", nullable = false)
    private User lastModifiedBy;
```

I have updated question with DTO and Entity model

Comment: Can you give an example of a property (In **RiskRequestDTO** and **Risk**) that was not mapped?

Comment: @HenriqueMentz have updated the question, i am facing mapping issue with all entity. But that is happening inconsistently.

Comment: Update your question with the Mapper instantiation code, it will help. Why didn't you do just do `riskList = modelMapper.map(risks, risksList)`? Also I can't understand the reason to use `Type`.

Comment: @HenriqueMentz made the changes suggested by you , no effect